JEXL expression to match with an array of regex?
Apache Commons JEXL has the operator In or Match, which is written as =~.
It works as a regex matcher if used with String on the right hand side:
"abcdef" =~ "abc.*"

It works as an in operator if used on an Array of String on the right hand side:
"a" =~ ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]

But how can it be used on an array of regexp, which means an array of string but these strings need to be evaluated by a regex matcher? The below obviously does not interprete the string values in the list as regex and thus returns false where I'd like to have true.
"abcdef" =~ ["abc.*", "a.d.*"]

I'd like to know both how to modify the JexlEngine (likely through Java code) and how to make use of that feature in a Jexl expression.

The question is valid; the solution lies in creating a derived JexlArithmetic that defines a 'public boolean contains(Pattern[] container, String str)' method which will overload the 'in' operator behavior. Can't post the code since the question is marked as closed for now...

Suppose I had created my derived JexlArithmetic. How would I tell the JexlEngine it exists?

https://github.com/apache/commons-jexl/commit/8a52b3b620e790e0abff19e90551677c10f3b1f6

Based on @henrib's answer I created this code which works for me on Jexl 3.4.0.
First of all I created a JexlArithmetic similar to the other solution, but it needs to override the contains(Object, Object) method:
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlArithmetic;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MatchingArithmetic extends JexlArithmetic {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
    
    public MatchingArithmetic(boolean astrict) {
        super(astrict);
        log.debug("MatchingAlgorithm({})", astrict);
    }

    public Boolean contains(Object container, Object value) {
        log.debug("contains({}, {})", container, value);
        if (container != null) {
            log.trace("container class: {}", container.getClass());
        }
        if (value != null) {
            log.trace("value class: {}", value.getClass());
        }

        if (container instanceof Pattern[] patterns) {
            log.debug("Pattern matching!");
            
            for(Pattern pattern : patterns) {
                if (pattern.matcher(String.valueOf(value)).matches()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
            
        } else {
            return super.contains(container, value);
        }

    }
    
}

Then I made use of that class like so:
import org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlEngine;
import org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlScript;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class JexlTest {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder()
                .arithmetic(new MatchingArithmetic(true))
                .create();
        
        JexlScript script = jexl.createScript("str =~ [\"abc.*\", \"def.*\"]", "str");
        log.info("{}", script.execute(null, "abcdef"));
        log.info("{}", script.execute(null, "defghi"));
        log.info("{}", script.execute(null, "ghijkl"));
        
        script = jexl.createScript("str =~ [~/abc.*/, ~/def.*/]", "str");
        log.info("{}", script.execute(null, "abcdef"));
        log.info("{}", script.execute(null, "defghi"));
        log.info("{}", script.execute(null, "ghijkl"));
    }

}

The output I get:
07:38:42.867 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - MatchingAlgorithm(true)
07:38:42.906 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - contains([abc.*, def.*], abcdef)
07:38:42.907 [main] INFO  JexlTest - false
07:38:42.907 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - contains([abc.*, def.*], defghi)
07:38:42.907 [main] INFO  JexlTest - false
07:38:42.907 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - contains([abc.*, def.*], ghijkl)
07:38:42.907 [main] INFO  JexlTest - false
07:38:42.908 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - contains([abc.*, def.*], abcdef)
07:38:42.908 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - Pattern matching!
07:38:42.908 [main] INFO  JexlTest - true
07:38:42.908 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - contains([abc.*, def.*], defghi)
07:38:42.908 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - Pattern matching!
07:38:42.908 [main] INFO  JexlTest - true
07:38:42.908 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - contains([abc.*, def.*], ghijkl)
07:38:42.908 [main] DEBUG MatchingArithmetic - Pattern matching!
07:38:42.908 [main] INFO  JexlTest - false

I was not aware the JexlEngine can detect strings as regex patterns if they are enclosed in ~/ and /. If this is a standard feature, maybe some pattern array matching could be part of the next Jexl release.

To expand or overload JEXL operators, you can derive JexlArithmetic and implement methods following the JexlOperator convention as documented here.
In your case, as an example:
public static class MatchingArithmetic extends JexlArithmetic {
    public MatchingArithmetic(boolean astrict) {
        super(astrict);
    }

    public boolean contains(Pattern[] container, String str) {
        for(Pattern pattern : container) {
            if (pattern.matcher(str).matches()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Test
void testPatterns() {
    final JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder()
            .permissions(JexlPermissions.UNRESTRICTED) // need this in Jexl 3.3 and later
            .arithmetic(new MatchingArithmetic(true))
            .create();
    JexlScript script = jexl.createScript("str =~ [~/abc.*/, ~/def.*/]", "str");
    assertTrue((boolean) script.execute(null, "abcdef"));
    assertTrue((boolean) script.execute(null, "defghi"));
    assertFalse((boolean) script.execute(null, "ghijkl"));
}


I tried the above code distributed over two classes. With Jexl 3.4.0 the contains(Pattern[], String) method does not get called at all. Is there something else required?

The usual culprit for method discovery failure is the class/method not being 'permitted'; the class and the method need to be public and the JexlPermissions must be configured to allow this class or its package.

Thank you for the hint. It is odd that a class added via the builder's add method is still not permitted. Could you show how to set permissions in your code?

Update: I noticed that contains(Pattern[], String) is getting called in Jexl 3.2.1 but not in 3.4.0.

The default permission behavior has changed in JEXL 3.3 as indicated in https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/relnotes34.html . The simplest way to start is to use something like 'final JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder().permissions(JexlPermissions.UNRESTRICTED)....' ; the permissions feature is described in https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jexl3/introspection/JexlPermissions.html
